Accessing Media3 MediaController in multiple fragments
I have created a PlayerService that inherits MediaSessionService and also has a MediaSession.Callback() as suggested by Android Media3 documentation.
Now in order to update the UI based on the PlayerService, I have created a MediaController using session token in Fragment_A. Now the UI elements in Fragment_A are updating correctly.
I want to access the MediaController in another fragment to update the UI of that Fragment too, say Fragment_B.
private lateinit var controller: MediaController
private var mediaControllerFuture: ListenableFuture<MediaController>? = null

private fun initializeMediaController() {
    val sessionToken =
        SessionToken(mContext, ComponentName(mContext, SongPlayerService::class.java))
    mediaControllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(mContext, sessionToken).buildAsync()
    mediaControllerFuture?.apply {
        addListener(Runnable {
            controller = get()
            updateStateWithMediaController(controller)
            handlePlaybackBasedOnState()
            setData()
        }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())
    }
}

I am calling initializeMediaController() inside onViewCreated() of the Fragment. I want the media controller in Fragment_B to connect to the same MediaSession.
Note: These 3 function are for updating UI and not related to accessing media controller directly:
updateStateWithMediaController(controller)
handlePlaybackBasedOnState()
setData()

